# jQuery/Javascript Ajax POST within .each loop creates 6 duplicate posts about 20% of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**Background:** jQuery mobile phonegap build multipage-ajaxload sisyphus enabled form with a ajax POST loop to a GUI database. There are 171 section posts, plus 1 summary post to a different table. (This data should probably be one post with the backend handling the logic, unfortunately I don't have the access or the time to fix this on the backend). About 80% of the time, this function does post 171 intended sections (plus the 1 summary post). However 20% of the time, there are 6 duplicate posts for a total of 177 posts. I've tried async:false, but there was a significant hit in performance.

Why are there 6 random duplicate posts roughly 20% of the time?
What is the best way to fix this ajax post loop so that there is not any skipped post or any duplicate post?

**HTML Submit Section:**

```
<form id="submit_section" encoding="multipart/form-data" encType="multipart/form-data">
    <br>
    <input type=hidden name=fform value=1>
    <input type="hidden" name="_fid_40" id="_fid_40" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_fid_48" id="_fid_48" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_fid_6" id="uniquetoktok" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sentstatus" id="sentstatus" value="" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="ID" required name="_fid_8" id="thisId" />
    <input type="hidden" required name="_fid_7" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your First & Last Name" required name="_fid_7" disabled="disabled"/>
    <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
    <input name="_fid_41" id="_fid_41" type="hidden" required>
    <div class="custom-select">
        <select name="_fid_41" type="text" required disabled="disabled">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="locationOne">locationOne</option>
        <option value="locationTwo">locationTwo</option>
        <option value="locationThree">locationThree</option>
        <option value="locationFour">locationFour</option>
        <option value="locationFive">locationFive</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="notyetsent">
        <a href="" class="senderbutton" data-theme="c" data-role="button">Submit Site Walk</a>
    </div>
    <div id="alreadysent">
        <span style="color:red;"><center>* This form has already been sent.</center></span><br>
        <a data-icon="plus" data-role="button" data-theme="b" href="#" class="photobutton" id="morephotos" rel="external">Add Photos</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

**HTML Form Format:**

```
<form id="check-2" encoding="multipart/form-data" encType="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="sendsendsend">
        <h4 style="display:none;">C1:</h4>
        <input type="hidden" name="_fid_14_C1" />
        <textarea style="display:none;" name="_fid_15_C1" /></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="sendsendsend">
        <h4 style="display:none;">C2:</h4>
        <input type="hidden" name="_fid_14_C2" />
        <textarea style="display:none;" name="_fid_15_C2" /></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="sendsendsend">
        <h4 style="display:none;">C3:</h4>
    <input type="hidden" name="_fid_14_C3" />
    <textarea style="display:none;" name="_fid_15_C3" /></textarea>
    </div>
</form>   ...  168 more '.sendsendsends'  ...
```

**jQuery Ajax 171 Post Loop:**

```
var totalRequests = 0;
var totalSuccess = 0;
var totalError = 0;

// Serialize #submit_section data and set to var formData to inject in sendsendsend loop
var formData = $('#submit_section').find("input, select").serialize();

// Posts each .sendsendsend divs (171 in total)
$('.sendsendsend').each(function() {
    var taskOrderData = $(this).find("input, textarea").serialize();
    var h4String = $(this).children('h4').html();
    var colonPosition = h4String.indexOf(':');
    var taskOrderId = h4String.substr(0, colonPosition);
    var postData = taskOrderData + '&' + formData + '&_fid_25=' + taskOrderId;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url',
            data: postData
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            totalSuccess++;
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            totalError++;
        }).always(function(a, textStatus, b) {
            totalRequests++;
            if (totalRequests >= 171) {
                if (totalError >= 1) {
                    $("#sentstatus").val("failed");
                    $.mobile.changePage('#failpop', {
                        transition: 'pop',
                        role: 'dialog'
                    })
                }
                if (totalSuccess >= 171) {
                    summaryPost();
                }
            }
        });
        function summaryPost() {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url',
            data: formData
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            totalSuccess++;
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            totalError++;
        }).always(function(a, textStatus, b) {
            totalRequests++;
            if (totalRequests >= 172) {
                if (totalError >= 1) {
                    $('.senderbutton').show();
                    $("#sentstatus").val("failed");
                    $.mobile.changePage('#failpop', {
                        transition: 'pop',
                        role: 'dialog'
                    })
                };
                    if (totalSuccess >= 172) {
                    $("#sentstatus").val("yes");
                    $.mobile.changePage('#successpop', {
                    transition: 'pop',
                    role: 'dialog'
                    });
                };
            };
        });
    };
})
```

It's a challenge just trying to replicate this issue on a mobile device. Any advice or suggestions would be wonderful!

Edit: Forgot to include the "Submit_Section"

Comment: Try making postData as a JavaScript object instead of a query string. This may eliminate any duplicate variables automatically.

Comment: I'm fairly new to js and jquery. To format postData as a JavaScript object, would you initialize postData as an object, or store the values like key-values pairs similar to a hash? Also, I read setting the cache:false might help. Do you think there is a correlation between the random posts and caching?

Comment: Never did find out why their were ajax batches that included 6 extra posts. I can only guess that one or more posts failed and Jquery reposted 6 automatically via ajax; This question was for use on a jQuery-mobile-form-based-QuickBase application (QB is a bit outdated, uses XML rather than JSON). The best solution I found was to use the QuickBaseAPI query ImportFromCSV and format the data for each record into CSV/CDATA. If anyone is interested in this I can make a JFiddle. If you need general advanced QuickBase + Jquery knowledge, Dan Diebolt is the QB guru.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently unrelated code wrapping your HTML form could be stimulating this behaviour.

In particular, if you have empty SRC or URL values, this can result in multiple page requests. One quick way to see if this is the case is to deliberately add an element with one of these mis-set values to your code and see if the incidence of multiple posts increased.

This can also be caused by these values being set inappropriately in your CSS definitions.

This is by design on some browsers; there's one request you ask for explicitly, and another that the browser itself kicks off as part of the process to try to resolve those empty values.

I got bitten by this a while back in a classic ASP application stack and it results in bizarrely chaotic behaviour when requesting / paging through results.